# Cannot make my background tasks workss with celery

Tags: python, celery

I am trying to process some tasks in the background in my flask app using celery. I follow the guide in the celery docs but I still can't make this works. I am using aws sqs as broker :

`tasks.py`

```
aws_access_key = safequote("XXXXXX")
aws_secret_key = safequote("XXXXXX")

broker_url = "sqs://{aws_access_key}:{aws_secret_key}@".format(
    aws_access_key=aws_access_key, aws_secret_key=aws_secret_key,
)

app = Celery('hello', broker=broker_url)

@app.task
def hello():
    print("hello !")
    return 'hello world'
```

`app.py`

```
from tasks import hello

@app.route("/")
def hi():
    hello.delay()
    return response(200,{
        'message': 'hello'
    })
```

When I make the request `hi` , I do get the response `hello` but the background task seems to not be executed as I didn't have the printed message `hello !` displayed in my logs.

Did I make something wrong ?

Comment: Did you start the celery worker?

Comment: @SharvariGc My whole app including the celery worker have been deployed to heroku so I guess the worker is started . Should I make some additional things to start it ?

Comment: No, just because the app has been deployed to heroku doesn't mean the worker is started try: `celery -A task.app worker --loglevel=info`  @Johndoe